# Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Bool' to expected argument type 'NSPredicate'

Tags: ios

I'm working with the filter() method in Swift 3, but encountering a problem, my code is....

```
filtered = arrayTag.filter(using: { (text) -> Bool in
        //Access the title and sectors
        let tmpTitle = text["tag_name"] as! String
        let tmpSector = text["tag_id"] as! String

        //Create a range for both
        let range1 = tmpTitle.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        let range2 = tmpSector.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        print("search result \(text)")

        //Return true if either match
        return range1 != nil || range2 != nil
    })
```

Comment: What type is `arrayTag`?

Comment: var arrayTag: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

Comment: `NSMutableArray` does not respond to `filter`. Use native Swift `Array`.

Comment: I convert NSMutableArray to native array -         var nativArray = arrayTag as NSArray as! [String] , but now giving me the error - Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((String) throws -> Bool)'

Comment: Do not convert or cast `NSMutableArray` to Swift Array, don't use the (mutable) Foundation collection types in Swift at all. Declare all array and dictionary types as native Swift types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of above problem

```
let tmpTitle = (text as! NSDictionary)["tag_name"] as? String
```

cast text `as! NSDictionary` .

Answer (score 0):

Method `filter(using:)` of `NSMutableArray` object takes `NSPredicate` as parameter. To use `filter` function change your code like:

```
filtered = arrayTag.filter { text in
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Same error -  Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Bool' to expected argument type 'NSPredicate'

Comment: Did you use `using` word in function?

Comment: yes,         filtered = arrayTag.filter(using: { (text) -> Bool in

Comment: Use example from my answer, it doesn't contain `using` word!

Comment: I use filter without using: but now problem in -  let tmpTitle = text["tag_name"] as! String,  Error - Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members

Comment: I also tried text:[String:Any] but after that it tell me to add as! (NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element) -> Bool after }. any suggestion

Comment: What your arrayTag contains? Try to cast it to [String:Any] type.

Comment: Thank you for your sugession.

Comment: Please approve my answer if it has helped you.